# Identity for the coefficients of trigonomeric polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $f=\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}c_n e_n=c_n e^{2\pi i nx} (n\in\mathbb{Z},x\in\mathbb{R})$ be a trigonometric polynomial. Then we have $c_n:=\langle f,e_n\rangle$   for all $-N\leq n\leq N$ and $\langle  f,e_n\rangle =0$ if $n > N$ or $n <  -N.$
>
> Also, we have the identity $\|f\|_2 ^2 =\sum_{n=-N}^{N} |c_n|^2$."

Now, I've managed to prove the first two identities and also that $\langle  e_n,e_m\rangle =1$ if $n=m$, $\langle  e_n,e_m\rangle =0$ if $n\neq m$ and $\|e_n\|=1$ but I haven't yet managed to prove that $\|f\|_2 ^2 =\sum_{n=-N}^{N} |c_n|^2$ (I tried by substituting $\ f=\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N}c_n e_n$ in the definition $\|f\|_2:=\sqrt{\langle  f,f\rangle }=(\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\overline{f(x)}dx)^{1/2}=(\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$ but without success) so I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: Use the fact that $\langle f, g \rangle$ is sesquilinear.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the term sesquilinear...that's linear in the first argument and conjugate linear in the second.

Comment: @P.Koymans done, thanks.